# How to deal with NA in sens.slope in r?

Tags: r

If I have this data:

```
library(trend)
v <- runif(100) * 1:100
func <- function(x,na.rm=T) { unlist(sens.slope(x)) }
func(v,na.rm=T)
```

everything went right and no problem. But in my real data there is NA.

```
v[1]=NA
func(v,na.rm=T)
```

I got this error:
 Error in na.fail.default(x) : missing values in object

Comment: Was the answer adequate? If so, could you please accept it, or point out why not? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set `v <- v[!is.na(v)]` first (before supplying `v` to `func`) and it should run fine.

Or else adjust your function, in which case the above is unnecessary:

```
func <- function(x,na.rm=T) {
 if(sum(is.na(x)) == length(x)) return(NA)
 if(na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)]
 unlist(sens.slope(x)) 
}
```